# TypeScript, how to properly use Array.prototype.reduce with Generic

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics, normalization, reduce

I am trying to normalize some data with Array.prototype.reduce.

I am wondering why I can break the "type-checking" in the `reduce` function.

Here is my interfaces.

```
interface Dict<T> {
  [key:string]: T;
}

interface InnerData {
  id: string;
  value: number;
}

interface RawData {
  innerData: InnerData[];
}

interface NormalizedData {
  innerData: Dict<InnerData>
}
```

Here are the samples on how I was planning to use these interfaces.

```
const rawData: RawData = {
  innerData: [
    {
      id: "ID_ONE",
      value: 1
    },
    {
      id: "ID_TWO",
      value: 2
    }
  ]
};

const normalizedData: NormalizedData = {
  innerData: this.noramlizeInner(rawData.innerData),
};

private noramlizeInner(innerData: InnerData[]): Dict<InnerData> {
  return innerData.reduce((acc:Dict<InnerData>, curr: InnerData) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [curr.id]: {
        ...curr
      }
    }
  }, {});
}
```

However, if I change the `normalizeInner`, I can still make it to compile, and the return valued is incorrect as expected.

```
private noramlizeInner(innerData: InnerData[]): Dict<InnerData> {
  return innerData.reduce((acc, curr: InnerData) => {      // changed acc:Dict<InnerData> to acc in the signature.
    return {
      ...acc,
      [curr.id]: [curr]
    }
  }, {});
}
```

Reiterating the question, I am wondering what I did wrong in the `reduce` function, why is it still compiling.

Here is the CodeSandBox app ([LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-bvm1j?file=/src/index.tsx:0-1096)) for demonstration.

Comment: Looks like a poor interaction between the empty object type `{}` inferred in `reduce()` and [implicit index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures).  Probably the fix here is to specify the generic like `innerData.reduce<Dict<InnerData>>(...)` instead of letting it be inferred as `{}`

Comment: (like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIhNAInMdkDeAsAFDLnLAAmAXMgM5hSgDmA3KRcgG5wA2AVwh0QAgLYAjaBxIBfUqVCRYiFFmAIwAHgAqAPkKcKAbQDWEAJ51GzECwC6dHTPklSMASE3AA9iGQgPlBwYnzAAF4Q6JhQABSgMTh4dNHYuHDG9gCUdOqaWqlQSXAGxGQUUBBgAlD+CWl4AHSVVAJIWnnahcV6erGxiAgANMgINVApGA1wWcgAvKVGXOSV1bWG5cvLjTuDQ0tbJmNQUI3UjoTIO43HUMiuh-cyXLIjBLJZLqSuCiRAA))

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a problem because your `Dict` interface accepts single object as property value

```js
interface Dict<T> {
  [key:string]: T;
}
```

but you try to assign array of objects

```js
private noramlizeInner(innerData: InnerData[]): Dict<InnerData> {
  return innerData.reduce((acc, curr: InnerData) => {      // changed acc:Dict<InnerData> to acc in the signature.
    return {
      ...acc,
      [curr.id]: [curr]
              // ^ this is array but Dict<InnerData> expects it as single object
    }
  }, {});
}
```

try enhance your dict to accept a array of objects also like this

```js
interface Dict<T> {
  [key: string]: T | T[];
}
```

or change your `reduce` function in order to return object instead of array of them

```js
  private noramlizeInner(innerData: InnerData[]): Dict<InnerData> {
    return innerData.reduce((acc: Dict<InnerData>, curr: InnerData) => {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [curr.id]: curr
      };
    }, {});
  }
```